# Will it be slow if a module is `required` several times in Browserify?

Tags: jquery, amd, browserify, commonjs

For example, codes in `a.js` looks like this

```
require('b')
$=require('jquery')
$.ready()
```

And codes in `b.js` looks like this

```
$=jQuery=require('jquery')
$.ready()
```

If I set `a.js` as the entry point, what will happen, as 'jquery' is required twice, will it be loaded twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in Node, the module code is only evaluated once. You can try this by putting a `console.log` statement in your module.